# Optimizing nested for-loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe containing a range of columns A, B, C, D (either 0 or 1) and a range of columns AB, AC, BC, CD that contain their interaction (also either 0 or 1).

Based on the interactions, I want to establish the existence of "triplets" ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD as in the following MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

np.random.seed(1)

df["A"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["B"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["C"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["D"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)

df["AB"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["AC"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["AD"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["BC"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["BD"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["CD"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)

ls = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for i, a in enumerate(ls):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(ls)):
        b = ls[j]
        for k in range(j + 1, len(ls)):
            c = ls[k]
            idx = a+b+c

            idx_abc = (df[a]>0) & (df[b]>0) & (df[c]>0)
            sum_abc = df[idx_abc][a+b] + df[idx_abc][b+c] + df[idx_abc][a+c]

            df[a+b+c]=0
            df.loc[sum_abc.index[sum_abc>=2], a+b+c] = 999
```

This gives the following output:

```
   A  B  C  D  AB  AC  AD  BC  BD  CD  ABC  ABD  ACD  BCD
0  1  0  0  0   1   0   0   1   1   0    0    0    0    0
1  1  1  1  0   1   1   1   1   0   0  999    0    0    0
2  0  0  0  1   1   0   1   0   0   1    0    0    0    0
3  0  1  0  1   1   0   0   0   1   1    0    0    0    0
4  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   0   1   1  999  999  999  999
5  1  0  0  1   1   1   1   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
6  1  0  0  1   0   1   1   1   1   1    0    0    0    0
7  1  1  0  0   1   0   1   1   1   1    0    0    0    0
8  1  0  1  0   1   1   0   1   0   0    0    0    0    0
9  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1    0    0    0    0
```

The logic behind the code is the following: A triplet ABC is active (=1) if at least two of the columns AB, AC, BC are active (=1) *and* the individual columns A, B, C are all active (=1).

I always start by looking at the individual columns (in the case of ABC then this is A, B and C). Looking at columns A, B and C, we only "keep" the rows where A, B and C are all non-zero. Then, looking at the interactions AB, AC and BC, we only "enable" the triplet ABC if at least two out of AB, AC and BC are 1 - which they are only for rows 1 and 4! Hence ABC = 999 for rows 1 and 4 and 0 for all others. This I do for all possible triplets (4 in this case).

The above code runs fast as the dataframe is small. However, in my real code the dataframe has more than one million rows and hundreds of interactions, in which case it runs extremely slow.

Is there a way to optimize the above code, e.g. by multithreading it?

Comment: Could you give a bit more explanation of the logic? This example isn't explicitly reproducible because you use random values for inputs. It would be helpful to see a static input, the output generated form that input, and the logic of what exactly a "triplet" is in this context?

Comment: This won't help with performance, but to clean up those loops you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: @G.Anderson I have added a seed and explained the logic a bit more. Please let me know if anything is still unclear

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks. I think I explicitly need the loop though as I need to loop at the individual components/columns A, B, C and D when investigating a triplet.

Comment: you don't need to multithread it, you need to learn how to pass what you need to mask functions. In the example, if 'ABC' is the same as 'A' & 'B' and 'C', you can use `df['ABC'] = 0; df['ABC'][(df['A'] ==1) & (df['B'] == 1) & (df['C'] == 1)] = 999`

Comment: @Mstaino Thanks! But the condition for having ABC=1 is that A=1, B=1, C=1 *and* at least two out of AB, AC and BC should 1. So `df['ABC'][(df['A'] ==1) & (df['B'] == 1) & (df['C'] == 1) & (df['AB']+df['AC']+df['BC'] >= 2)]`

Comment: What are the dimensions of the data?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I have almost 3000 triplets (corresponding to almost 30 "individual" columns A, B, C, ...) and 500.000 rows

Comment: @TylerD great then (I didn't understand the condition from your data). The point is, replace the `for` loop by a mask operation (way faster). Also, if you only have 0-1, you should probably use `bool` data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that is about 10x faster than your reference code. It does nothing particularly clever, just pedestrian optimization.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

np.random.seed(1)

df["A"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["B"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["C"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["D"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)

df["AB"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["AC"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["AD"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["BC"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["BD"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
df["CD"] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)

ls = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

def op():
    out = df.copy()
    for i, a in enumerate(ls):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(ls)):
            b = ls[j]
            for k in range(j + 1, len(ls)):
                c = ls[k]
                idx = a+b+c

                idx_abc = (out[a]>0) & (out[b]>0) & (out[c]>0)
                sum_abc = out[idx_abc][a+b] + out[idx_abc][b+c] + out[idx_abc][a+c]

                out[a+b+c]=0
                out.loc[sum_abc.index[sum_abc>=2], a+b+c] = 99
    return out

import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

def pp():
    data = df.values
    n = len(ls)
    d1,d2 = np.split(data, [n], axis=1)
    i,j = np.triu_indices(n,1)
    d2 = d2 & d1[:,i] & d1[:,j]
    k,i,j = np.ogrid[:n,:n,:n]
    k,i,j = np.where((k<i)&(i<j))
    lu = ssd.squareform(np.arange(n*(n-1)//2))
    d3 = ((d2[:,lu[k,i]]+d2[:,lu[i,j]]+d2[:,lu[k,j]])>=2).view(np.uint8)*99
    *triplets, = map("".join, combinations(ls,3))
    out = df.copy()
    out[triplets] = pd.DataFrame(d3, columns=triplets)
    return out

from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import combinations, chain

def make(nl=8, nr=1000000, seed=1):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    letters = np.fromiter(ascii_uppercase, 'U1', nl)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for l in chain(letters, map("".join,combinations(letters,2))):
        df[l] = np.random.randint(0,2,nr,dtype=np.uint8)
    return letters, df

df1 = op()
df2 = pp()
assert (df1==df2).all().all()

ls, df = make(8,1000)

df1 = op()
df2 = pp()
assert (df1==df2).all().all()

from timeit import timeit

print(timeit(op,number=10))
print(timeit(pp,number=10))

ls, df = make(26,250000)
import time

t0 = time.perf_counter()
df2 = pp()
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print(t1-t0)
```

Sample run:

```
3.2022583668585867 # op 8 symbols, 1000 rows, 10 repeats
0.2772211490664631 # pp 8 symbols, 1000 rows, 10 repeats
12.412292044842616 # pp 26 symbols, 250,000 rows, single run
```